# sequelize.literal return both the origin attribute name and the attribute after renaming

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, sequelize.js

I want to rename attributes after doing `join`, i tried to use `sequelize.literal` in nodejs but it returns both the origin name and modified name. How can i remove the origin name from result?

```js
const result = await User.findAll({
  attributes: [
    'name',
    'id',
    [Sequelize.literal('Company.name'), 'companyName'],
    [Sequelize.literal('Employee.type'), 'employeeType'],
  ],
  include: [
    { model: Company, attributes: ['name'], required: false },
    { model: Employee, attributes: ['type'], required: true },,
  ],
  raw: true,
});
```

Result:

```js
...
"companyName": "Test",
"employeeType": "Junior",
"Company.name": "Test",
"Employee.type": "Junior",
```

Desired Result:

```js
...
"companyName": "Test",
"employeeType": "Junior",
```

Comment: have you tried removing those two `Sequelize.literal`'s ?

Answer (score 1):

I just found out a solution to this question, But i'm open to other ideas

Here's what I did and it works well with me.

```js
const result = await User.findAll({
  attributes: [
    'name',
    'id',
    'Company.name',
    [Sequelize.literal('`Company`.`name`'), 'companyName'],
    'Employee.type',
    [Sequelize.literal('`Employee`.`type`'), 'employeeType'],
  ],
  include: [
    { model: Company, attributes: [], required: false },
    { model: Employee, attributes: [], required: true },,
  ],
  raw: true,
});
```